# existence of LU factorization

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

I am given a matrix $M=E-\alpha X$, where $E$ is an identity matrix, $0<\alpha<1$, and $0 \le X_{i,j} \le 1$ and the sum of every column of $X$ is 1.

Does the matrix $M$ always exist a LU  factorization ?

Answer (score 1):

Each leading principal [minor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_(linear_algebra)) of the matrix $M^T$, as constructed, is [strictly diagonally dominant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonally_dominant_matrix), hence nonsingular.  This is precisely the [condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition#Square_matrices) needed for an LU decomposition to exist.

Comment: only $M^T$ has an $LU$ decomposition. that $M^T$ has an $LU$ decomposition does it imply $M$ has?

Comment: $(M^T)^T=(LU)^T=U^TL^T$, which is again lower triangular times upper triangular.  Or, once you know the leading principal minors of $M^T$ are nonsingular, then you equally know the leading principal minors of $M$ are nonsingular.

Comment: i see now. i guess, $M$ is nonsingular guarantees that both $L$ and $U$ have non zero diagonal entries. thanks.